# source ~/.rvm/source/rvm

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rvm

Once in a while when working on my Rails app I try to use the Rails command and I get this error:

```
The program 'rails' can be found in the following packages:
 * rails
 * ruby-railties-3.2
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

This happens over and over.  I try `gem install rails` and it doesn't help.  I have to first run `source ~/.rvm/source/rvm` and then `gem install rails`.  But then after a short while the same thing starts happening.

Comment: what means 'after a short while'?

Comment: Sorry, I have not quantified the time between when the Rails command works and when it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you missed to read instructions from installer and rvm commands, follow this simple instruction https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/ - it might be a bit different for your default terminal emulator.